# How to parse a string using a CSV parser in Python?

Tags: python

I need to parse a string using a CSV parser. I've found this solution in many places, but it doesn't work for me. I was using Python 3.4, now I changed it to 2.7.9 and still nothing...

```
import csv
import StringIO

csv_file = StringIO.StringIO(line)
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for data in csv_reader:
      # do something
```

Could anyone please suggest me another way to parse this string using a CSV parser? Or how can I make this work?

Obs: I have a string in a CSV format, with fields that have commas inside, that's why I can't parse it in the standard way.

Comment: Please read the guide on how to construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); you didn't even explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around elements that contain commas.

The CSV format implements [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2), which states:

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.

So for instance (run code [here](http://repl.it/ejE/1).):

```
import StringIO
import csv

# the text between double quotes will be treated 
# as a single element and not parsed by commas
line = '1,2,3,"1,2,3",4'

csv_file = StringIO.StringIO(line)
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for data in csv_reader:
    # output: ['1', '2', '3', '1,2,3', '4']
    print data
```

---

As another option, you can change the delimiter. The default for `csv.reader` is `delimiter=','` and `quotechar='"'` but both of these can be changed depending on your needs.

**Semicolon Delimiter:**

```
line = '1;2;3;1,2,3;4'

csv_file = StringIO.StringIO(line)
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
for data in csv_reader:
    # output: ['1', '2', '3', '1,2,3', '4']
    print data
```

**Vertical Bar Quotechar**

```
line = '1,2,3,|1,2,3|,4'

csv_file = StringIO.StringIO(line)
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quotechar='|')
for data in csv_reader:
    # output: ['1', '2', '3', '1,2,3', '4']
    print data
```

Also, the python `csv` module works on python [2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html) - [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fileformats.html), so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution that jumps out of the page, rather than reimplementing CSV parsing, is to preprocess the data first and replace all of the commas within strings by some never used token character (or even the word COMMA), then feeding that into the CSV parser, and then going back through the data and replacing the tokens back with commas.

Sorry, I've not tried this myself in Python, but I had issues with quotes in my data in another language, and that's how I solved it.

Also, Bcorso's answer is much more complete. Mine is just a quick hack to get around a common limitation.